# O que são Raw Types?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, kotlin

Lendo e estudando um pouco sobre o Kotlin, encontrei a seguinte afirmativa:

> Os *Raw Types* são um grande problema, mas por motivos de
>   compatibilidades eles tiveram que ser mantidos no Java, mas o Kotlin
>   por ser uma linguagem nova não possui mais esse problema.

O que são exatamente os *Raw Types*? E porque eles são um grande problema?

Comment: [Documentação da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) Um tipo bruto é o nome de uma classe genérica ou interface sem qualquer tipo de argumento.

Comment: Quem negativou a pergunta poderia pelo menos explicar o motivo para que eu possa edita-la e tentar colaborar mais com nossa comunidade!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## O que são exatamente Raw Types?

De acordo com a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8), em tradução livre:

> Mais precisamente, um tipo bruto é definido como sendo um dos
>   seguintes:
>
> - O tipo de referência que é formado tomando o nome de uma declaração de
>     tipo genérico sem uma lista de argumento de tipo de acompanhamento.
> - Um tipo de matriz cujo tipo de elemento é um tipo bruto.
> - Um tipo de membro não estático de um tipo bruto R que não é herdado de
>     uma superclasse ou superinterface de R.

O termo [Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) ficou conhecido com a introdução do [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html).

Para exemplificar, irei utilizar o [Framework Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html):

Quando o Collections foi concebido na versão 1.2 do Java, uma coleção não especificava qual tipo de objeto manipularia, ou seja, a coleção poderia receber qualquer tipo, como no exemplo:

```
List lista = new ArrayList();
lista.add(1);
lista.add("teste");
```

Manipular uma coleção desbalanceada como está é custoso, pois quando você tira um elemento da coleção, você deve atribui-lo ao seu respectivo tipo, alem de ser inconveniente, não é seguro. 
O fato de não informar um tipo/argumento ao [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) é conhecido como um Raw Type, ou em tradução livre, um tipo bruto.

#### Solucionando o Raw Type:

Para resolver esse problema, na versão 1.5 do Java foi introduzido o [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html), com isso, possibilitou-se informar um tipo a coleção, conforme o exemplo:

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
lista.add("teste_0");
lista.add("teste_1");
```

Sendo assim, uma vez que o compilador conhece o tipo de elemento da coleção, o compilador pode verificar se você usou a coleção de forma consistente e pode inserir os moldes corretos sobre os valores que estão sendo retirados da coleção.

## E porque eles são um grande problema?

De fato, os Raw Types são um grande problema, pois, mesmo com a introdução do Generics não seria conveniente remover os Raw Types, pois as aplicações legadas precisam continuar em funcionamento.

Comment: O único detalhe que noto é que enquanto o Java 5 e 6 exigem `List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();` para não dar uma warning do tipo rawtypes, a partir do Java 7 pode-se usar `List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa , operador diamante é lindeza e alegria, evita muita repetição de nome do tipo