# Como obrigar o usuário a passar um tipo para uma classe genérica?

Tags: java, genéricos

Eu tenho uma classe genérica chamada `Quantity<UnitType>`, e em alguns métodos de uma outra classe, eu preciso obter um objeto dessa classe em um tipo específico. Veja o código abaixo:

```
interface UnitType {}

enum Distance implements UnitType {
    FEET, METERS
}

enum Weight implements UnitType {
    POUNDS, KILOGRAMS
}

class Quantity<T extends UnitType> {
    public Quantity(float value, T unit) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.func(new Quantity<Weight>(30, Weight.KILOGRAMS));
    }

    public static void func(Quantity<Weight> value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

O código acima compila, como esperado. O problema é que se eu não especificar o tipo na inicialização e passar como argumento um atributo de `Distance`, o código também compilará.

```
// Compila. Isso é um problema, pois o método só aceita "Weight"
Test.func(new Quantity(30, Distance.FEET)); 

// Não compila. É isso o que eu quero.
Test.func(new Quantity<Distance>(30, Distance.FEET));
```

O que eu posso fazer para obrigar o usuário a passar um tipo para a classe genérica, ou então, "filtrar" os objetos que sejam apenas de `Weight`?

Comment: Eu acho que isso é um conceito errado, mas ainda adotando acho que não tem o que fazer. Não conheço Java profundamente, mas eu infiro não ser possível. Temo até ser um problema do Java, posso estar enganado, mas se eu sou o criador da linguagem eu faria o contrário, ou seja, só aceitaria explicitamente já que pode haver ambiguidade, inferência só quando não há. Claro que sempre tem solução, mas não do jeito que está fazendo. Não respondo porque não tenho certeza nem disso nem o quanto dá para fazer diferente no problema. Mas fiquei curioso com o Java.

Comment: @Maniero A menos que eu tenha interpretado a pergunta muito errado, dá sim para fazer o que ele quer e é algo até que relativamente simples e fácil.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não funcionou: https://ideone.com/mwcteh. Foi a primeira coisa que eu fiz, na verdade eu até usei `Weight` porque `UnitType` é justamente o que ele não quer, ele quer `Weight` apenas. Mas ambos o compilador aceita e infere erado.

Comment: @Piovezan a pergunta é justamente essa.

Comment: @Maniero Editei a resposta abaixo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é uma solução, não que faça o mesmo que ele fazia, complica um pouco, e me parece que por falha da linguagem. Como eu disse, não tem jeito na forma que ele quer. Mais tarde eu farei mais alguns testes.

Comment: Acho que esta pergunta é boa e útil à comunidade, coisa que tem sido rara nos últimos tempos. Quem quer que seja que deu voto negativo, poderia explicar a motivação?

Comment: Questão relacionada que pode ajudar a entender melhor o problema dos *raw types* em Java: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/229885/157404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem que declarar o método `func` como genérico se quiser que funcione para qualquer `UnitType` e com tipos genéricos (`Quantity<T>`).

No entanto, se você quiser utilizar um tipo específico, você apenas usa o tipo desejado (`Quantity<Weight>`, como no exemplo do `funcW` abaixo).

Você também pode usar o *diamond* (`<>`) para simplificar os seus genéricos ao usar o `new`. Por exemplo, `new Quantity<>(20, Weight.KILOGRAMS)`.

No entanto, ao usar o construtor diretamente você ainda tem que ou colocar o tipo genérico `<Weight>` ou o *diamond* `<>` para não recair no problema da sua pergunta. Ainda é possível esquecer de colocar qualquer um deles (ou seja, usar *raw types*), e portanto o *diamond* ainda não resolve o seu problema, apenas o atenua.

A causa do problema é que dada a forma como a linguagem Java evoluiu, com a adição dos tipos genéricos apenas tardiamente no Java 5 e considerando que a compatibilidade com versões anteriores não podia ser sacrificada, não há uma forma muito melhor de se usar construtores com tipos genéricos. Poderia haver se a linguagem já tivesse nascido com isso desde o começo, mas infelizmente não é esse o caso.

A solução definitiva então é não usar o construtor diretamente. E é aí que um método estático resolve o problema. Nesse método estático chama-se o construtor que é então tornado privado. Isso inviabiliza o uso de *raw types* e a possibilidade de utilizarem-se genéricos mal-formados.

Eis o código:

```java
interface UnitType {}

enum Distance implements UnitType {
    FEET, METERS
}

enum Weight implements UnitType {
    POUNDS, KILOGRAMS
}

class Quantity<T extends UnitType> {
    private Quantity(float value, T unit) {
        // ...
    }

    public static <T extends UnitType> Quantity<T> create(float value, T unit) {
        return new Quantity<>(value, unit);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.func(Quantity.create(30, Weight.KILOGRAMS));  // Compila.
        Test.func(Quantity.create(30, Distance.METERS));   // Compila.
        Test.funcW(Quantity.create(30, Weight.KILOGRAMS)); // Compila.
        Test.funcW(Quantity.create(30, Distance.METERS));  // Não compila.
    }

    public static <T extends UnitType> void func(Quantity<T> value) {
        // ...
    }

    public static void funcW(Quantity<Weight> value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: O código da resposta funciona como eu queria. Porém, como o Maniero falou, ele ficou mais complicado, e como eu ainda sou novo em Java, o código está um pouco confuso para mim. Pode explicar melhor isso? E por que no início da resposta você disse que é necessário declarar o método como genérico se eu quisesse utilizar qualquer `UnitType`, visto que isso já ocorre e é justamente o meu problema?

Comment: Além disso, por que o código só funciona se a instância for criada pelo método estático e não normalmente, através do construtor público?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Funciona também se for criado pelo construtor. Mas nesse caso, você tem que colocar o tipo genérico `<Weight>` ou então o diamond `<>`. Se não colocar nem um e nem outro recai no seu problema original. A causa do problema é que a forma como genéricos em construtores foi feita não ficou muito boa (e como a compatibilidade com Java < 5 não podia ser sacrificada, não poderia ser muito melhor). A solução então é não usar o construtor diretamente, e é aí que o método estático resolve o problema.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Na sua pergunta, não ficou 100% claro se o que você quer é que funcione com qualquer genérico (`<T>`) ou apenas com um específico (`<Weight>`). Ao lê-la pela primeira vez, entendi que era o primeiro caso. Considerando os comentários do Maniero e após reler, parecia que era o segundo caso e agora acho que era isso mesmo o que você procurava. No entanto, ao invés de ficar debatendo como interpretar a pergunta ou como ela deveria ser redigida, achei melhor, mais produtivo e mais amigável colocar a solução para ambas as situações e daí todo mundo fica contente e satisfeito. 

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Na hora que escrevi a resposta, eu estava meio com pressa e não deu para detalhar muito bem. Agora eu revi com mais cuidado e mais calma a redação desta resposta e acredito que esteja satisfatória. Se ainda tiver alguma dúvida, pode perguntar aqui nos comentários. 

Comment: Finalmente eu consegui entender o problema e a solução que você deu. Muito obrigado Victor!